# Trying derive $a=v^2/R$ with complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, physics

I'm trying to derive the radial acceleration formula for uniform circular motion: $a =v^2/R$.

Here's what I've
$\mathbf r(t)= Re^{-it/2}\mathbf e_1e^{it/2}$
$\implies \ddot {\mathbf r}(t) =\frac R{16} (-\cos(t/2) +i\sin(t/2))\mathbf e_1(-\cos(t/2)-i\sin(t/2)) = \frac 1{16} \mathbf r(t)$

This isn't exactly what I want.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need more details: how do you define $r(t)$ to get that formula to start with?

Comment: I figure since $e^{-i\theta/2}\mathbf ve^{i\theta/2}$ is the formula for rotating a vector $\mathbf v$ in the plane by angle $\theta$ that should the formula for $r$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: I think you are confusing some concepts. If $z$ is a complex number in the plane then $e^{i\theta/2}$ rotates that number (viewed as the vector $(x,y)$ where $z=x+iy$) by $\theta/2$. However $e^{i\theta/2}$ is a scalar and does not rotatate vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ unless you specifically represent them as a complex number. But even if you do then $e^{i\theta/2}ze^{-i\theta/2} = z$ as all the terms commute. I suspect you might have seen operator identities like $e^{i\theta/2}Ae^{-i\theta/2}$ in quantum mechanics which rotates spin, but then $\theta$ is a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use $z(t) = re^{i\omega t}$ to indicate the position vector of the particle as a complex number on the plane of motion. $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and it is constant, as is $r$.

You now get $v(t) = \frac{dz}{dt} = i\omega re^{i\omega t} = i\omega z(t)$, which has magnitude given by $|v(t)| = r\omega$, as expected. The complex form tells you the angular velocity is perpendicular to the position vector, also as expected (remember that multiplying by $i$ rotates a complex number counterclockwise through $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

By differentiating again, you get $a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} = -\omega^2 re^{i\omega t} = -\omega^2 z(t)$. The magnitude is given by $|a(t)| = r\omega^2$, again as expected. The complex form tells you the acceleration vector is antiparallel to the position vector (i.e. collinear but oppositely directed - that's centripetal acceleration).

You can use the magnitude formulas to rearrange to get the form you require.

$|v(t)| = r\omega \implies \omega = \frac{|v(t)|}{r}$

$|a(t)| = r\omega^2 = r \cdot {(\frac{|v(t)|}{r}})^2 = \frac{{(|v(t)|)}^2}{r}$